# Attach icon to link on MuPDF

Tags: android, mupdf

I am using MuPDF library in my android project. I implemented it clearly and it's working fine. In my PDFs there is lots of link to navigate browser, but users can't figure out them. I want to add a icon over layouts where the items has got navigation link. How can I do that?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. 
In PageView.java class, there is a method called `**setPage(int page, PointF size)**`
There is a block which is drawing content on highlight links.

```
if (!mIsBlank && mLinks != null && mHighlightLinks) {
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
                    for (LinkInfo link : mLinks) {
                        RectF rectfa = new RectF((link.rect.left - 2) * scale, (link.rect.top - 2) * scale, (link.rect.right + 2) * scale, (link.rect.bottom + 2) * scale);
                        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                        paint.setColor(LINK_COLOR);
                        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectfa, 3 * scale, 3 * scale, paint);

                        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                        paint.setColor(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
                        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectfa, 3 * scale, 3 * scale, paint);

                        int left = (int) ((link.rect.left - 2) * scale);
                        int right = (int) ((link.rect.right + 2) * scale);
                        int top = (int) ((link.rect.top - 2) * scale);
                        int bottom = (int) ((link.rect.bottom + 2) * scale);

                        Rect dstRectForRender = new Rect(right - bitmap.getWidth(), top, right, top + bitmap.getHeight());
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRectForRender, null);// I draw my bitmap on here.
                    }
                }
```